# How to add a toolbox to the MATLAB path

Tags: matlab

Downloaded a library of functions from the internet. Drag and dropped it into the `matlab` directory (which is my default directory). I try to call these functions and nothing happens. They are several subfolders deep (`matlab/fieldtrip/etc/etc`). How do I access these functions from my workspace?

Answer (score 2):

You should [**read the documentation that came with the toolbox**](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/faq/should_i_add_fieldtrip_with_all_subdirectories_to_my_matlab_path) since it may have toolbox-specific installation instructions. In your case it looks like you just need to add the `fieldtrip` directory to your path.

```
addpath('matlab/fieldtrip')
```

Then you'll have to run the `ft_defaults` install script that they provide which will theoretically handle all of those nested directories for you.

```
ft_defaults
```